# Is it possible to build a script in Hyperion that autologs required credentials into the ODS(sql database) when the queries are run?

Tags: javascript, hyperion

It will be painfully obvious I'm new to the space so apologies in advance for lack of code/maybe even understanding.

I'm using Oracle Hyperion financial reporting software and connecting to the ODS regularly to get data updated and am tired of logging into the database(s) each time I run the .bqy file queries.

Is there a javascript code that can be run on the hyperion side that would auto login in the required credentials? I realize this may be inefficient compared to trying to add a user access to the database directly, but trust me it will be very difficult to do at this point in time.

Thanks for any tips you may have.

Comment: Hyperion what?  Hyperion is a suite of products.  For example, are you asking about Hyperion Interactive Reporting Studio?  Hyperion Interactive Reporting web client connected to Hyperion Reporting and Analysis?  Hyperion Planning?  Hyperion Financials?

Comment: I used Hyperion Interactive Reporting -- both the desktop and client -- and managed the Hyperion Reporting and Analysis server, but that was a lifetime ago (before support ended 8 years ago?).  I don't remember logging in to the desktop client, so we must have had Active Directory groups with permissions assigned on the database server.  I also had single signon for the server, so users never manually logged in.  For the web client, I think it's possible to set up the data sources on the server with SQL logins and manage permissions to the data sources or reports.  Again, it's been a while.

Comment: No JavaScript.  It's all configured on the server.